# Converting a GeoTiFF to an integer raster

Tags: integer, raster

I am trying to convert a float raster to an integer raster in QGIS. I even tried looking for options in GDAL but haven't had any luck so far. Is there a way to convert a float raster to an integer in QGIS ?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you share your prior attempts of fixing the problem and what went wrong with them, so that others can better help you? Your question is a bit hard to answer right now.

Comment: I tried using this code in Raster->Conversion->Translate gdal_translate -of GTiff -ot Int32 "E:/Test/sample_raster.tif" "E:/Test/sample_raster2.tif" but could not edit the code in the GDAL/OGR console call

Answer (score 0):

You can use gdal to do this from the command line. For example, I was able to convert a 64-bit floating point grayscale image to 16-bit integer samples using

```
gdal_translate -ot Uint16 in.tif out.tif
```

See https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html for possible output types.